# Iterate through and array which contains another array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have the following object being returned from a post request

```
"{\"Success\":false,\"Errors\":{\"Name\":[\"The Name field is required.\"],\"Id\":[\"The Id field is required.\"],\"SortOrder\":[\"The SortOrder field is required.\"]}}"
```

I need to iterate through the Errors object and find the Id field and highlight it on my page. How would i go about doing this? I can iterate through a simple array but this response looks like its an array which contains another array.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `JSON.parse` in order to parse the string into a JavaScript object, then retrieve the `Id` like this:

```js
const response = "{\"Success\":false,\"Errors\":{\"Name\":[\"The Name field is required.\"],\"Id\":[\"The Id field is required.\"],\"SortOrder\":[\"The SortOrder field is required.\"]}}";

const parsed = JSON.parse(response);

console.log(parsed.Errors.Id[0]);
```